# How to simulate Single precision rounding with Doubles?

Tags: floating-point, double, floating-accuracy, ieee-754

i had a problem where i was trying to reconstruct the the formula used in an existing system, a fairly simple formula of one input and one output:

```
y = f(x)
```

After a lot of puzzling, [we](http://sacredduty.net/2012/09/14/avoidance-diminishing-returns-in-mop-followup/) managed to figure out the formula that fit our observed data points:

[image]

And as you can see our theoretical model fit observed data very well:

[image]

Except when we plot residual errors (i.e. `y = f(x) - actualY`), we see some lines appear in the residuals:

[image]

It was obvious that these lines were the result of applying some intermediate rounding in our formula, but it was not obvious *where*. Eventually it was realized that the **original** system (the one we're trying to reverse engineer) is storing values in an intermediate **`Decimal`** data type:

- with **8-bit precision** of the fraction
- using the **0.5 round-up** rounding model:

We could *simulate* this 8-bit precision in the fraction by:

```
multiply by 128 (i.e. 2^8)
apply the round
divide by 128 (i.e. 2^8)
```

Changing our equation above into:

[image]

This reduces the residual errors *significantly*:

[image]

Now, all of that above has no relevance to my question except:

1. To show that simulating the numerical representation in the computer can help the model
2. To get people's attention with pretty pictures and colors
3. Silence critics who [would](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972829/how-to-call-use-net-rijndaelmanaged-from-native-com) [refuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323303/how-to-inherit-from-control-rather-than-usercontrol) to [contribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224220/win32-how-to-make-drop-shadow-honor-non-rectangular-layered-window) until i [explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111618/win32-how-to-validate-credentials-against-active-directory) *why* i'm asking my question

---

Now i want to simulate **`Single Precision`** floating point numbers, inside a programming language (and Excel) which use **`Double Precision`** floating point numbers. i want to do this because *i **think*** it is what's needed.

In the above example i **thought** the original system was using a *`Decimal data type with fixed 8-bit fractional precision using 0.5 round-up rules`*. i then had to find a way to simulate that computation model with `Double` math. Now i *think* the original system is using `Single` precision math, that i want to simulate using `Double`.

> How do i simulate single-precision rounding using doubles?

In my current model, i once again have residuals that fall into the regular linear patterns - that are a tell-tale sign of rounding:

[image]

The problem is that the error becomes larger, and only visible, as my input variables become larger. i realized this is likely caused by the fact that all floating point numbers are normalized into [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) "scientific notation".

And even if i'm wrong, i still want to try it.

And even if i don't want to trying it, i'm still asking the question

> How do i simulate `Single` precision rounding using `Doubles`?

---

It seems to me i could still apply the concept of *"rounding after 8 fractional bits"* (although 24 bits for `Single` precision floating point), as long as i can first *"normalize"* the value. e.g.

```
1234567898.76543
```

needs to be converted into (something similar to):

```
1.23456789876543 E-09
```

Then i could apply my "round to the 24th bit" (i.e. 2^24 = 16,777,216)

```
floor(1.23456789876543E-09 * 16777216 + 0.5) / 16777216;
```

The problem, then, is what combination of `sign`, `abs`, `ln`, `exp` (or other functions) can i possible apply so that i can "normalize" my value, round it to the n-th binary place, then "denormalize" it?

**Note**: i realize IEEE representation keeps a binary `1` as the most significant bit. i might not need to duplicate that behavior in order to get correct results. So it's not a deal-breaker, nor is it cause to suggest that the entire approach is a failure.

## See also

- [How to emulate single precision float operations in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130688/how-to-emulate-single-precision-float-operations-in-php)
- [Simulate single precision arithmetic in Matlab?](http://www.mathworks.cn/matlabcentral/answers/35085-simulate-single-precision-arithmetic-in-matlab)
- [IEEE 754 Floating Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)

Comment: Are you looking for generic answers or will language-specific answers do?

Comment: @Neil Ideally it will work in Excel and in Lua. As a bonus it will work in C# Double, Dephi Real, and Javascript number.

Comment: I'm not smart enough to develop a working solution but couldn't you solve this by treating the double as a binary value and set the training (53-23) bits of the mantissa to zero? Rounding would probably be more complicated, but doable.

Comment: @usr Lua (like Excel) has no ability to cast a floating point memory into a structure in order to provide direct bit access.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to use the library functions frexp and ldexp, which are standard C99 functions, and are available in Lua.

frexp takes a floating point number and separates the mantissa from the exponent. The resulting mantissa is either 0 or in one of the ranges [0.5, 1.0) or (-1.0, 0.5]. You can then remove any extra bits in the obvious way (`floor(mantissa * 2^k)/2^k` for non-negative values, for example). (Edited to add:) It would be better to subtract k from the exponent in the call to ldexp than to do the divide as shown, because I'm pretty sure that Lua doesn't guarantee that 2^k is precise.

ldexp is the inverse of frexp; you can use that to put the truncated number back together again.

I have no idea how to do this in Excel. Check the manual :)  (Edited to add:) I suppose you could get roughly the same effect by dividing the number by 2 to the power of the ceiling of the log 2 of the number, and then doing the binary round as indicated above, and then reversing the process to recreate the original exponent. But I suspect the results would occasionally run into peculiarities with Excel's peculiar ideas about arithmetic.

Comment: Nice. Simple. Pragmatic. Thank you so much for the insightful answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can get most of the effect of rounding to single precision using:

```
y = x + x * 0x1p29 - x * 0x1p29;
```

In most cases, this produces the same result in y as if x had been rounded to float (32-bit binary IEEE 754) and then converted back to double (64-bit). It works by adding a value (x * 0x1p29) that “pushes” some bits of x out of the significand, causing rounding at bit 23, and then subtracting the value that was added. (`0x1p29` is hexadecimal floating-point for 2<sup>29</sup>, 536870912.)

In rare cases, it produces a slightly different result. If you merely want to reduce noise in a model, these rare cases might be negligible. If you want to eliminate them, then, instead of adding and subtracting 2<sup>29</sup>x, you could find the largest power of 2 not greater than x and add and subtract 2<sup>29</sup> times that instead of 2<sup>29</sup>x. (To find the power of 2, you can take the base-two logarithm and take the floor of that. However, there are still rounding issues that might require compensation. Additionally, if the input might be zero or negative, you must avoid the error that occurs when taking its logarithm.)

Additionally, this does not reproduce the behavior for numbers that are subnormal in single-precision or that overflow in single-precision.

Finally, there are rare cases where computing a double-precision result and then rounding to single precision produces a result slightly different from computing a single-precision result originally, and no method of rounding the double-precision result will fix this.

Comment: What's constantly in the back of my mind is that the original system can *consistently* reproduce these values. It's not some random magic going on - it's an algorithm in a computer. At some level the laws of computing say i should be able to reproduce the math.

Comment: @IanBoyd, you can, see my answer. (ldexp and frexp just twiddle bits, they don't do complicated computations in the background.) So they give you precisely the result you're looking for. (At least if you're using some kind of C variant or Lua. Or, I just checked, Python.)

Comment: @IanBoyd: Of course the computation can be replicated. However, there is no reason that should be easy given the operations available in Excel.

Comment: i'm going to give it to rici, but you have a very good solution also. i noticed that `x+x*2^29-x*2^29` gives the same results as my original `floor(x*c+0.5)/c` routine. i don't know *why*, but details of floating point operations are never obvious.

Comment: To your last point, that's not *quite* true.  If the original double-precision result were rounded with the "round inexact to odd" rule, then you can round that to single without introducing a double rounding.  We're way off in the weeds of floating-point arithmetic (and way off of what there is hardware or language support for) at that point, however.

Comment: @StephenCanon Probably my only next bet is to dig out the assembly language debugger.

Comment: @StephenCanon: “No method of rounding the double-precision result will fix this” means there is no function of the already obtained double-precision result that always produces what would have been obtained in single-precision. That is, it is a statement about what we can do after obtaining the double, not about how we can round it before it is final. (And we are in no danger of Excel providing “round inexact to odd.”)

Comment: If the formula uses only basic IEEE 754 operations (as the OP's does), another relevant reference may be “When is double rounding innocuous?” by Samuel A. Figueroa. I did not read it, I only had it summarized to me by an expert, but if I do not mis-remember, there is never a double rounding issue when rounding to single-precision the result of a double-precision basic operation on single-precision operands.

Answer (score 1):

Use code like this (C):

```
double x, y;
/ ... y gets a double value somewhere ... /
x = (double)(float)y;
```

After that, x (double) will have a value resulted from rounding of y as single precision float.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom function using a  module in **Excel VBA**:

```
Function SINGLEFLO(Eingang As Double)
    Dim MySingle As Single
    MySingle = CSng(Eingang)
    SINGLEFLO = CDbl(MySingle)
End Function
```

Then you can use `SINGLEFLO()` in all Excel Cells were you need limiting precision to `Single Float`.